# Jasper server parameter issue with PHP

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I would like to generate reports in pdf format with following scenario:

Jasper reports are in jasper server and I want to get that report from another server by passing parameters to it. The main issue occurred here is that I'm not able to pass parameters.

The language is `php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call *JR Server*'s web services via *PHP*.

[This article](http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog/articles/DOMM-6J2QFF) is about how to call web service from *PHP*.

And this [wiki page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api) and this [document](http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-5-0/JasperServer-Web-Services-Guide.pdf) are about ***JasperReports Server Web Services***.

If you have installed *JR Server* you can find the samples in ***`<js-install>/samples/php-sample`*** folder.

Comment: Main issue is that complete jasper reports are running within japer server and i want to call that reports from another server which is a php. I called that reports but parameter passing is not working

Comment: Did you try to use the samples from JasperServer distribution pack? Are they work?